# Empathy does not connect automatically

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, empathy

The Empathy chat client on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine logs into chat accounts (Gmail and Facebook) only after I have opened the client once (it starts on system boot) this is a bit irritating as I often forget to do it after booting my machine. Is there a setting that I am missing or is this a an unanswered bug in Empathy ?

Answer (score 2):

`System – Preferences – Startup Applications` to en- or disable. I then also added the `-h` switch to the command to hide the contact list when it starts.

or try this

`sudo cp /usr/share/applications/empathy.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart

 sudo chmod a+r /etc/xdg/autostart/empathy.desktop`

Comment: did not work , empathy is in the startup but it will login only when I maximize the window once

Answer (score 1):

Per answer from kracekumar, I had to add empathy.desktop to the autostart directory:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/empathy.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart
sudo chmod a+r /etc/xdg/autostart/empathy.desktop
```

Additionally, I added the line:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

works for me on Ubuntu 11.10